# How do you remove a node?

Tags: scenekit

May I get an example?
To add a node, I do this:

```
let thisNode = thisScene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("someGraphic", recursively: true)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(thisNode!)
```

Now how do I remove it? I've read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNNode/removeFromParentNode) backwards and forwards and still can't do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is applied just like on a view or a layer:

```
thisNode.removeFromParentNode()
```

Comment: I had to add some flair for it to work but it works. thisNode!.removeFromParentNode() Thanks.